# How did you setup OAuth2 using aws Cognito

Tags: pkce

Can you help me out to understand how did you setup OAuth2 PKCE over AWS Cognito. AWS documentation is somehow confusing me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be to use the Amplify SDK for interacting with Cognito's OAuth endpoints as it implements PKCE for you:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js

Even if you do not wish to use the Amplify SDK, it would be a good start to see how it implements PKCE with Cognito.